# Transparent Shadow View

Tags: android, xml, view, transparency, shadow

Im trying to implement a transparent shadow like in the google play app.
When you scroll down the tiles lie behind the shadow but you can see them throw it. See example picture here:

[image]

I created a view for that which I can add in a layout by

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar_shadow" />
```

**toolbar_shadow.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**shadow.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:centerColor="#33333333"
        android:endColor="#aa666666"


        android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

What I got is a shadow that is not transparent. When a tile moves behind it, it gets covered by white/grey* color.

*endColor="#aa666666" from shadow.xml

Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: Could you post the whole layout file which includes the shadow?

Answer (score 1):

try this but change gradient color for your need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="#0eb0a0"
    android:startColor="#0e9083">
</gradient>
</shape>
```

оr just put toolbar into appbarlayout

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:elevation="3dp">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this way to add transparent shadow. Because your shadow area is within your bar and android don't allow transparent background in the first activity. One word, you should add your shadow at the top of the list layout which is below your top bar. Wish it's useful to you.